# Mock file input for unit test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I got something like these lines of code:

```
jQuery('.js-img-input').on('change', handleNewFiles);   

var handleNewFiles = function(event) {
    var fileList = event.target.files;
    loadFileList(fileList);
};

var loadFileList = function(fileList) {
    jQuery(fileList).each(function(key, file) {
        readFileAsync(file);
    });
}

var readFileAsync = function(file) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        file.result = event.target.result;
        saveFile(file);
    });
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

All of the methods are private inside a jQuery-function and I don't whant to make "handleNewFiles" public just for testing purpose.
I would love to test these lines with something like this:

```
it('should create a fileReader', function(){
    spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue({
        addEventListener: function(){},
        readAsDataURL: function(){}
    });
    jQuery('.js-img-input').trigger('change');
    expect(window.FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But how did I get some dummy data into **event.target.files**?

Answer (score 3):

Alright I find a solution. You can't create a faked native event with files and for security reasons that's a good thing. But in my case the solution looks like this:

```
it('should create a fileReader', function(){
  var onChangeCallback;
  spyOn(jQuery.fn, 'on').and.callFake(function(eventName, callback){
    if(eventName === 'change'){
      onChangeCallback = callback;
    }
  });
  spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue({
    addEventListener: function(){},
    readAsDataURL: function(){}
  });
  onChangeCallback({target:{files:[1,2,3]}});
  expect(window.FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Fix onChangeCallback({target{files:[1,2,3]}}); please. You are missing a colon there.
It should be: onChangeCallback( {target: {files:[1,2,3]}} );

Comment: Added colon. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While you can't assign a value to `fileInput.files`, you can replace the property with your own, which accomplishes the same thing:

```js
it('should create a fileReader', () => {
    const fileInput = $('input[type=file]');
    const fileInputElement = fileInput.get(0);
    Object.defineProperty(fileInputElement, 'files', {
      value: [{name: 'file.txt'}],
      writable: false,
    });
    fileInput.trigger('input').trigger('change');

    // expect outputs...
});
```

This is a bit better than creating your own event object, since it simulates the real environment a little more closely.

Answer (score 1):

this article may helps

http://nerds.intuo.io/2016/05/12/mocking-file-uploads-in-javascript.html

```js
function fillInFileInput(selector, file) {
  // Get the input
  let input = jQuery(selector);

  // Get out file options
  let { name, type, content } = file;

  // Create a custom event for change and inject target
  let event = jQuery.Event('change', {
    target: {
      files: [{
        name: name, type: type
      }]
    }
  });

  // Stub readAsDataURL function
  let stub = sinon.stub(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsDataURL', function() {
    this.onload({ target: { result: content }});
  });

  // Trigger event
  input.trigger(event);

  // We don't want FileReader to be stubbed for all eternity
  stub.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a slightly modified solution based on Jakob's answer. I needed some slight modifications to get it to work for me. This worked for me using "angular": "1.0.6", "jasmine-node": "1.3.1", "jquery": "1.10.0"

```js
var onChangeCallback;

spyOn(jQuery.fn, 'on').andCallFake(function(eventName, selector, callback){
  if(eventName === 'change'){
    onChangeCallback = callback;
  }
});
spyOn(window, 'FileReader').andReturn({
  addEventListener: function(){},
  readAsDataURL: function(){}
});

onChangeCallback({currentTarget: {files:[{size: 4000}], value: 'asd'}});
```